# Works of Rav Moshe ibn Chaviv

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, commentaries

If I'm not mistaken a popular series of *sefarim* for Maseches Rosh Hashanah, Yoma, and Sukkah, are respectively "Yom Teruah", "Tosefes Yom Hakippurim", "Kapos Temarim", by [Rav Moshe ibn Chaviv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_ibn_Habib).

I've seen these in the ubiquitous "kovetz meforshim" collection of commentaries on these masechtos, but I don't recall seeing these seforim published on their own, at least in recent prints. Is there a modern printing of these works? Are there different versions? What are their respective merits/demerits? Do any have footnotes/commentaries? Are they always published together, or as separate volumes?

Answer (score 3):

It's available together in one volume, under the name of שמות בארץ. It was reprinted recently and should be in many seforim stores. There are no footnotes, but it's a nice clear print.

https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5-%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%97%D7%91%D7%99%D7%91

Comment: The introduction is excellent, too!